# How to workaround unwanted TestNG assertEquals overloads

Tags: java, testng

I am having a problem where some class X extends extends java.util.AbstractMap, and also overloads `equals(Object)`.  Calling `org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(X a, X b)` resolves to `assertEquals(Map<?,?>, Map<?,?>)`.  Instead of calling the 'equals' method, the map entries are compared.  This results in `assertEquals(a, b)` passing even though `a.equals(b)` is false.

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AssertTest {
    static class X extends AbstractMap<String, Object> {
        private int i;

        public X(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof X && i == ((X)o).i;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
        return i;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        X one = new X(1);
        X two = new X(2);
        assertEquals(one, two); // passes, should fail IMO
        assertTrue(one.equals(two)); // correctly fails
    }
}
```

What is the best way to work around this problem?  One possibility is to remember to not use `assertEquals` to verify that instances of X match, but that is extremely error-prone.

Another possibility is to simply make a local copy of testng and rename the overloads.  That creates an ongoing maintenance problem.

The only other idea I have is to create a project-specific Assert class that delegates to testng.Assert but renames the problematic overloads to 'assertCollectionEquals', 'assertMapEquals', etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(X a, X b)` calls [the `assertEquals(Map, Map)` method](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/Assert.java#L816) which iterates over the entry set and checks that all entries are equals, bypassing the `Map#equals` method, as you have noticed.

A simple cast would avoid calling that method and would use the `X#equals` method instead:

```
assertEquals((Object) one, (Object) two);
```

You could also declare your variables as objects to achieve the same result:

```
Object one = new X(1);
Object two = new X(2);
assertEquals(one, two);
```

That does not realy solve your issue in the sense that it still is error prone.

To avoid the occasional error, there are a few workarounds I can think of (getting tired here so some might make little sense), using the fact that `assertEquals` without cast calls `x.entrySet()`:

- write some code that parses all your test files for X class and make sure that there is a cast in place (not straightforward) or that no `X` is declared on the left of an `=`
- use a mocking framework and mock X in a `@BeforeGroups` method (if you use groups) and put each test that relies on that idiom in the same group, so that they will use a mocked X where entrySet fails your tests (and the other methods work as expected), or at least logs/prints some warning. If you also need to use `entrySet` in the same method that won't work
- use a mocking framework to mock `TestNG#assertEquals(Map, Map)` to get the desired behaviour
- in all the test classes that need that idiom, create an ad hoc `assertEquals(Map, Map)` method. If you have a static import of all assertEquals method you will have to reimplement the other signatures too :-(
- have all those test classes inherit a BaseXTestClass where you implement an `assertEquals(Map, Map)` method - same caveat

Comment: sorry, the test code was in error, and equals was properly overridden.  However, the assertEquals call is resolved to assertEquals(Map, Map) which then does entry-by-entry comparison without checking for an overriding equals method.

Comment: @kevincline That makes more sense ;-) Changing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the possibilities.  It's a pretty ugly situation.  I think that TestNG.assertEquals should always call a.equals(b), and if that fails, then attempt to analyze the structure when possible.  For now I'm going to just try to remember to call a special method for this class.

Comment: @kevincline To be honest I was not aware that it was doing that and I find the behaviour surprising too. I see that you have submitted an issue - that makes sense.